# Optimal Item Locations given Traversal Paths

Tags: algorithms, graphs, graph-traversal, euclidean-distance

I have a given fully-connected undirected graph associated with (known) distances or alternatively a distance matrix, where the nodes or matrix rows/columns represent locations.

Additionally, I have a number of items smaller or equal to the number of locations, as well as a finite number of traversal paths for the items.

A traversal path is a fixed order in which the items are supposed to be passed through by passing through the locations the items are placed in. The traversal time/traversal distance is calculated by adding the traversal distances between the different locations that are passed through. Also, all traversal paths start and end at the same location.

I now try to find an (approximately) optimal way to allocate the items in the locations (e.g. leading to a minimal average traversal time/distance), without trying every possible allocation.

How can this problem be approached? What are useful algorithms for solving it and what computational complexity do they have?

Comment: How do you define a traversal path for an item?

Comment: Also, can you describe how the traversal time depends on the allocation of items to locations?  What is the definition of the traversal time?

Comment: I edited the question, I hope it is clear now.